# Fixing *.sh error line 5: [: missing `]' with spacing around brackets correct

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
./regen_structs_proto.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
./regen_structs_proto.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

I am getting errors like the above ones when when I run the following Bash script (line 5 is the first line of the script below):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ docker --version | grep -q "Docker version" ]; then
    echo "Check that docker is installed: confirmed."
else
    if [ lsb_release -si | grep -q "Linux" ]; then
        if [ lsb_release -si | grep -q "Ubuntu" ]; then
            apt-get update;
            apt-get install -y docker;
        elif [ lsb_release -si | grep -q "Manjaro" ]; then
            sudo pacman -S --needed docker;
        else
            echo "installation for Docker is not configured for your OS, please install manually and make a pull request to install in this script for your OS";
        fi
    fi
fi
```

How can I fix these errors? I have triple checked that the spacing around the brackets is correct.

Comment: A pipe separates two commands. Thus, you're trying to run one command `[ docker --version` and a separate command `grep -q "Docker version" ]`. The first one is a `[` without a closing `]` (and with contents that aren't [valid `test` syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)), the second has `grep` trying to read from a file named `]` (rather than its stdin).

Comment: BTW, this is a category of bug that http://shellcheck.net/ can catch automatically (it links to https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1014).

Comment: Also, it'd be way more efficient to only run `lsb_release` once, even if you want to compare its output against several different things. `lsb_release=$(lsb_release -si); if [[ $lsb_release = *Linux* ]]; then case $lsb_release in *Ubuntu*) apt-get update; apt-get install -si docker;; *Manjaro*) sudo pacman -S --needed docker;; *) echo "installation for Docker not configured for your OS" >&2; exit 1;; esac; fi`

Comment: ...using a `case` statement (thus, internal shell logic) is way more efficient than spinning up `grep` to just check for whether a single, short string has a substring.

Comment: Very helpful comments! Did you mean to use `-si` in `apt-get install -si docker;`, instead of `-y`? Thanks to shellcheck, `if [[ $lsb_release = *Linux* ]];` has a warning that it is non-POSIX compliant, so I changed it to if [ `"$lsb_release" ] = [ *Linux* ]; then`.

Comment: @JamesRay `if [ "$lsb_release" ] = [ *Linux* ]; then` is not valid syntax in *any* unix shell. I'd recommend spending some time studying shell syntax, rather than just trying things and then wondering why it doesn't work. First thing to realize: the thing between `if` and `; then` is a *command*. You can use any command there, but `[` (yes, it's a command) is common; it interprets its arguments as a test expression (except for its last argument, which must be "]"). Note that trying to use additional `[` and `]` characters inside that expression doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JamesRay `[[ ]]` is different from `[`, as it's not a command (though you can use it in place of one), it's actually shell syntax. It's basically a cleaned-up version of `[ ]`, with some additional capabilities like pattern matching (e.g. `[[ $lsb_release = *Linux* ]]`). But it's not available in all shells. `case` *is* available in all POSIX shells, so that's the preferred portable way to do pattern matching. Or you could just make your script explicitly a bash (rather than plain sh) script by changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, then use all the bash extensions you want.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: this might be semantics, `type [[` gives `shell keyword` but `man bash` refers to `[[` as a "compound command" in more than one place.  However the syntax for `if` is given as *if list;* (POSIX says "compound-list").  It seems that `[[` was omitted from the standard because the problem was the mis-use of `[` and `[[` was the wrong solution to that.  Nothing has changed!

Comment: @JamesRay, if you want POSIX compliance, use `case $lsb_release in *Linux*) ...;; esac` instead of switching to `[ ]`. That said, I'd just use a `#!/bin/bash` shebang -- that way you can reasonably use extensions that add value, `[[ ]]` among them.

Answer (score 3):

The brackets are `test`. If you don't need `test`, then don't use brackets.

```
if docker ... | grep ... ; then
   ...
fi
```